# Can i use "sender" in Akka FSM code?

Tags: scala, akka, scala-2.10, fsm, gen-fsm

```
class RulesFSMActor extends Actor with FSM[State, Data]{
  When(Rule1)
  {
    case Event(CASE_MSG1, Data) => 
      if (<someconditon>)
        goto(Rule2)
  }
  When(Rule2)
  {
    case Event(CASE_MSG2, Data) => 
    if (<someconditon>){
      sender ! MessgeBackToCaller"    // Is it allowed to use "sender" ?
      goto(Rule1)
  }
 }
//unhandled ,...etc
}
```

Assume my initial state is "Rule1" and it keeps toggling between states, If its in "Rule1" , it moves to "Rule2" and vice versa ,  based on some condition it has to send a message back to Caller(Sender).

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. FSMs are normal actors with the receive implemented to handle states.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course! FSM's are only an extension (a "domain specific language") for defining Actors which have multiple states.

Comment: if the fsm pipes a message to self in is the sender now self?

Comment: yes but you can put the information about `initial` sender in the data and pass it across states